# MySQL: how to select many results from linked table at one row to another?

Tags: sql, mysql

At first - Im sql newbie, sorry for this (mbe typicall) question.

I Have two table: table of organisations...

```
id_org    org_name
1         Organiz1
2         Organiz2
```

and table of organization staff.

```
id_staff  staff_name   id_org
1         John         1
2         Jack         1
3         Sally        1
4         Peter        1
5         Andy         2
6         Joe          2
```

I want sql answer(two rows) like this

```
1 Organiz1 1 John 2 Jack 3 Sally 4 Peter
2 Organiz2 5 Andy 6 Joe
```

and I want what each name or id of staff will be named as staff_1_name(staff_2_name,staff_3_name) and staff_1_id.
How I can get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT o.id_org, o.org_name, GROUP_CONCAT(concat(s.id_staff, ' ', s.staff_name) ORDER BY s.id_staff SEPARATOR ' ')
 FROM Organizations o, staff s
 WHERE s.id_org = o.id_org
 GROUP BY id_org, org_name;
```

Comment: Good answer, but string concatenation in MySQL won't work with the `+` operator. You'll have to use `CONCAT()`.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks. Replaced to concat. (Its nightmare, oracle use '||', sql-server - '+', mysql - concat)

Comment: I agree... Especially for such a basic operation.

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck. MySQL offers a handy function called [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) which you can use to build that result set:

```
SELECT o.id_org, o.org_name, GROUP_CONCAT(s.staff_name_id SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM   organisations o
JOIN   (
          SELECT id_staff, 
                 id_org,
                 CONCAT(id_staff, ' ', staff_name) staff_name_id 
          FROM staff
       ) s ON (s.id_org = o.id_org)
GROUP BY o.id_org, o.org_name;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE organisations (id_org int, org_name varchar(20));
CREATE TABLE staff (id_staff int, staff_name varchar(20), id_org int);

INSERT INTO organisations VALUES (1, 'Organiz1');
INSERT INTO organisations VALUES (2, 'Organiz2');

INSERT INTO staff VALUES (1, 'John',  1);
INSERT INTO staff VALUES (2, 'Jack',  1);
INSERT INTO staff VALUES (3, 'Sally', 1);
INSERT INTO staff VALUES (4, 'Peter', 1);
INSERT INTO staff VALUES (5, 'Andy',  2);
INSERT INTO staff VALUES (6, 'Joe',   2);
```

Result:

```
+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------+
| id_org | org_name | GROUP_CONCAT(s.staff_name_id SEPARATOR ' ') |
+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------+
|      1 | Organiz1 | 1 John 2 Jack 3 Sally 4 Peter               |
|      2 | Organiz2 | 5 Andy 6 Joe                                |
+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

[@Micahel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821783/mysql-how-to-select-many-results-from-linked-table-at-one-row-to-another/3821821#3821821) also returns the same result. I recommend using that solution since you can concatenate your fields directly in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, instead of using a derived table:

```
SELECT    o.id_org, 
          o.org_name, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(id_staff, ' ', staff_name) SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM      organisations o
JOIN      staff s ON (s.id_org = o.id_org)
GROUP BY  o.id_org, o.org_name;
```

Comment: big thanks to you answer. but I want to declare their names as fields (staff_1_name ...) It is possible?

Comment: @0dd_b1t: Oh I see. MySQL doesn't support Pivot Tables (which is what you're looking for). There are some workarounds, but pretty complex. You may want to search on Stack Overflow or Google for MySQL Pivot tables... That is unless you require a maximum number of users. In that case, you could solve the problem quite easily, using a join for each level of depth.

Comment: thx to you, and thx for this big answer and answers:) But (you need to understand me) i marked michael answer as best.